# Defaultdic sum does not print in python

Tags: python

```py
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {('03/24/21', 'BLUE', '390'): 176.0, ('03/24/21', 'BLUE', '391'): 182.0})
```

Instead of printing as per the above with the : indicating the sums, I want to print each item separately like:

```py
{('03/24/21', 'BLUE', '390'): 176.0 ........ new line
('03/24/21', 'BLUE', '391'): 182.0
```

However when I try

```py
for d in dictionary:
 print(d)
```

output:

the sum is missing.i only get:

```py
{('03/24/21', 'BLUE', '390') ..........new line
('03/24/21', 'BLUE', '391')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in dictionary.items(): print(d)
```

Comment: thank you however, now  everything gets repeated